# ArrayBlockingQueue always returns true

Tags: java, android, multithreading, concurrency, android-camera

So I tried to implement a consumer - producer pattern in android the scenario is as such:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView ... {

     .......

     public ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer> mProcessingQueue;

     public CameraPreview(){
           mProcessingQueue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<ByteBuffer>(10);
          HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("Image Processing Thread");
          handlerThread.start();
          Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
          handler.post(new Runnable() {
              @Override
              public void run() {
                  new ImageProcessingThread().start();
              }
          });
      }


     public void onPreviewFrame(final byte[] data, Camera camera){

          .......

          if(!mProcessingQueue.offer(byteBuffer)) {
              byteBuffer.clear();
              Log.v("IMAGE_AVOIDED", count + "");
          } else {
              Log.v("IMAGE_PUSHED", count + "");
          }

     }

     public void processImage(ByteBuffer image){

          .. call to opencv jni function .. 

     }

     public class ImageProcessingThread extends Thread{
          int count = 0;

          @Override
         public void run() {
             super.run();

             while(mImageProcessingRunning){
                 try {
                     ByteBuffer image = mProcessingQueue.take();
                     Log.v("IMAGE_TAKEN", count++ + "");
                     processImage(image);
                     image.clear();
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
             }
         }
     }

}
```

However when I run this code .. it never produces the IMAGE_AVOIDED log statement .. it alternates between IMAGE_TAKEN and IMAGE_PUSHED .. one frame is pushed .. and one frame processed ..

I was hoping I'd be able to constantly place frames into mProcessingQueue and when the consumer thread was ready, to take from the queue .. this way I could drop frames if the queue was full and only place the latest frames into the queue as to get closer to real time ..

I'm sure its a synchronization problem .. maybe I'm running the same two threads in one process and therefore the scheduler is hoping back and forth through tasks ?

Any ideas / pointers ??

Comment: Sounds like the consumer thread's processing is fast enough that the queue never fills up...

Comment: I was thinking of that but it cant be, the producer should run 30 fps probably closer to 20 given time to fill ByteBuffer with data, and the time to execute the JNI code is definitely slower than real time

Comment: Introduce a sleep or hang in your consumer method to make sure the queue is filled up, and see what happens.

Comment: Looks like a sleep shows I can fill up the queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the above implementation is correct .. however I was doing some calculations in the onPreviewFrame function call .. which gave the consumer thread enough time to execute the work at hand .. Thanks all !